# Curl sending xml file via post

Tags: python, xml, post, curl

I am confused on why using the following fails with 500 error:

curl -i -X POST --user auser@customer5 -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @test.xml http://appdyn.unx.com:8090/controller/healthrules/96?overwrite=true

but, this works:

curl -i -X POST --user auser@customer5 -F file=@test.xml http://appdyn.unx.com:8090/controller/healthrules/96?overwrite=true

Why would setting a header correctly to text/xml and using --data-binary fail?  Note I used instead of --data-binary -F file= option too, and that fails with 500 error.  I am curious to know what curl is doing different with the simpler command that makes it work.  I kind of want to know this so I can translate what it is doing over to a python script later.

Comment: Note I ran with -v option and see Content-Type, which I added to the curl call:  curl -v -X POST --user auser@customer5 -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------5e4815b6a9f1" -F file=@test.xml http://appdyn.unx.com:8090/controller/healthrules/96?overwrite=true and that worked too.  I switched -F file= with --data-binary, but that fails,so it seems to come down to -F file= option that is making it work.  What is that doing?  How do we do the same in python?

Comment: did you try without specifying the Content-type with --data-binary option

Comment: Vikas, yes I tried that combo too.  It seems to ONLY work if I use either the option of setting Content-Type to multipart/form-data with -H AND the use of -f File=@test.xml.  or I do not set a Content-Type at all and use -f File=@test.xml.